# Is this select subquery avoidable?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables (Invoices and taxes) in mysql:

```
Invoices:
  - id
  - account_id
  - issued_at
  - total
  - gross_amount
  - country

Taxes:
  - id
  - invoice_id
  - tax_name
  - tax_rate
  - taxable_amount
  - tax_amount
```

I'm trying to retrive a report like this

```
rep_month  | country | total_amount | tax_name | tax_rate(%) | taxable_amount | tax_amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-01 | ES      | 1000         | TAX1     | 21          | 700            | 147
2017-01-01 | ES      | 1000         | TAX2     | -15         | 700            | 105
2016-12-01 | FR      | 100          | TAX4     | 20          | 30             | 6
2016-12-01 | FR      | 100          | B2B      | 0           | 70             | 0
2017-01-01 | GB      | 2500         | TAX3     | 20          | 1000           | 200
```

The idea behind this is that an invoice has a `has_many` relation with taxes. So an invoice can have or not taxes. The report should show the total amount collected (`total_amount`) for a given country (regardess if it includes taxes)
and indicate which part of that total amount is taxable (`taxable_amount`) for an specific tax.

My current approach is this one:

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(invoices.issued_at, '%Y-%m-01') AS rep_month,
invoices.country AS country
( SELECT sum(docs.gross_amount)
  FROM invoices AS docs
  WHERE docs.country = invoices.country
  AND DATE_FORMAT(docs.issue_date, '%Y-%m-01') = rep_month
) AS total_amount,
taxes.tax_name AS tax_name,
taxes.tax_rate AS tax_rate,
SUM(taxes.taxable_amount) AS taxable_amount,
SUM(taxes.tax_amount) AS tax_amount
FROM invoices
JOIN taxes ON invoices.id = taxes.document_id
AND documents.issue_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY account_id, rep_month, country, tax_name, tax_rate
ORDER BY country desc
```

Well, this works but for a real dataset (thousands of records) it's really slow as the `select` subquery for retrieving the `total_amount` is being run for each row of the report.
I cannot make a `LEFT JOIN taxes` with a direct `SUM(gross_amount)` as the `GROUP BY` groups by tax name and rate and I need to show the total collected per country regardless if the amount was taxed or not. Is there a faster alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact use case of using this query but the issue is the way with which you're trying to structure the DB, you're trying to get the entire data in one go.

Ideally, you should run the query you have and store in a different table (summary table) and then query directly from the summary table whenever you want. And if you have a new entry in the Invoices table then you can use the query to run either on every entry or periodically update the summary table via a cronjob.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, the ideal case would be having a table with the report already stored acting as a cache. This query is precisely required for building the report for the first time so I can have the report table populated with data to work with upcoming cron jobs.

Comment: @John then there should be no issue if the query took a few seconds longer. It's right the way it is!